# How can I determine the user who provided the correct arguments when using the command?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I make a game of roulette, everyone probably knows.
Problem:
I have arguments that need to be cited correctly, but I need to get the user who cited those arguments correctly.
Question:
How can I do it?
I haven’t tried it, I don’t know how to do it :) I hope you can help, thanks! Code below

```
     
 @commands.command(brief = '''
            Использование команды:
            Поставить на число: JM!wheel number (число) (ставка)
            Поставить на цвет: JM!wheel color (red или black) (ставка)
            Поставить на чет-нечет JM!wheel vs (even = чет, odd = нечет) (ставка)''')
    async def wheel(self, ctx, mode = None, value = None, bet = None):
        result = random.randint(0, 36)
        numbers_red = ['1', '3', '5', '7', '9', '12', '14', '16', '18', '19', '21', '23', '25', '27', '30', '32', '34',
                       '36']
        numbers_black = ['2', '4', '6', '10', '11', '13', '15', '17', '20', '22', '24', '26', '28', '29', '31', '33',
                         '35']
        numbers_even = ['2', '4', '6', '8', '10', '12', '14', '16', '18', '20', '22', '24', '26', '28', '30', '32', '34', '36']
        numbers_odd = ['1', '3', '5', '7', '9', '11', '13', '15', '17', '19', '21', '23', '25', '27', '29', '31', '33', '35']


        if mode == None and value == None and bet = None:
            await ctx.send('''
            Использование команды:
            Поставить на число: JM!wheel number (число) (ставка)
            Поставить на цвет: JM!wheel color (red или black) (ставка)
            Поставить на чет-нечет JM!wheel vs (even = чет, odd = нечет) (ставка)''')
        if mode and value and bet:
            if mode == 'color':
                if value in numbers_red and result in numbers_red:
                    pass
                elif value in numbers_black and result in numbers_black:
                    pass
                elif value in numbers_green and result == '0':
                    pass


            elif mode == 'number':
                if value == result:
                    pass


            if mode == 'vs':
                if value in numbers_odd and result in numbers_odd:
                    pass
                if value in numbers_even and result in numbers_even:
                    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to use this code:

```
user = ctx.message.author
```

So that you will know who used the command.
Idk if you asked for this...
Otherwise you may need to know who is the author of a message, you can fetch the message and then get the author.

```
user = fetch_message(ID).author
```

Hope it was usefull